# Create filter for li in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, filter, html-lists

I'm not so familiar with javascript and for most of you it will be very easy but...

I'd like to create filter for my li> tag. Found this code on the internet which is basically the same but using div> and I'm unable to modify that to use it on li>

Here's my code.

```
<button class="active button" id="all">Show All</button>
<button class="button" id="a">Show A</button>
<button class="button" id="b">Show B</button>
<button class="button" id="c">Show C</button>
<button class="button" id="d">Show D</button>

<div id="parent">
  <ul class="rig columns-3">
    <li class="a">
      <img src="image_1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="b">
      <img src="image_1.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the script I'm using:

```
var $btns = $('.button').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('#parent > li').fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
    $('#parent > li').not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Could anyone help me please? I'd very appriciate that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{element a} > {element b}` is a selector for a direct child. This means in that case `#parent > li` will target `<li>` tags just after the tag with id `parent` and not thoses inside another tag like this

```
<div id="parent">
    <li>
    <--!This will be selected>
    <li>
    <div class="child">
        <li>
        <--!This will not be selected>
        </li>    
    </div>
</div>
```

In your case, you could use`#parent > ul > li` or just `#parent li` this doesn't needs li to be a first child of tag with id `parent`

In that case your script would look like this

```
var $btns = $('.button').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('#parent > ul > li').fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
    $('#parent > ul> li').not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: Or simply remove `>` in OP selector. No real needed for nested children specificity

Comment: Yes it's working !

I used:

<div id="parent">
  <ul>
    <li class="a">
    <--!This will be selected>
    <li>
  </ul>
</div>
If anyone was wondering...

Thank you for quick response. Both of you guys :-)